# Регулярное выражение preg_match (Поиск всех символов кроме цифр)

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

Здравствуйте.

Есть у меня регулярное выражение.

```
$match = '43243';

    @preg_match('([0-9]+)', $match, $title);

echo $title[1];
```

В общем, проблема такая: находит регулярка цифры, но нужно, чтоб не находило цифры, когда в `$match` есть еще и символы. Как сделать?

Comment: \d >>>> [0-9]

Answer (score 3):

Всё, кроме цифр:

```
preg_match('/[^\d]+/', 'foo123bar', $match);
var_dump($match);
```

Для нескольких вхождений:

```
preg_match_all('/[^\d]+/', 'foo123bar', $match);
var_dump($match);
```

P.S. Использование оператора подавления ошибок `@` является дурным тоном. В данном конкретном случае он вообще нецелесообразен.

Comment: > Использование оператора подавления ошибок @ является дурным тоном. 

хуже только запятая между подлежащим и сказуемым

Answer (score 1):

Можно попробовать так:

```
^[0-9]+$
```

П.С. Не используйте в коде собак "@", пожалуйста.

Comment: @czart2014, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).